# I18n in Rails for filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, rails-i18n

I have a problem I am unable to solve with internationalization in Rails. I am completely newbie in Rails.

I have a collection of categories defined in room.rb:

```
  CATEGORY_COLLECTION =  {
                  I18n.t('meeting_rooms') => "sala-de-reuniones",
                  "Aula de formación" => "aula-de-formacion",
                  "Sala para entrevistas" => "sala-para-entrevistas",
                  "Espacio para Eventos de Empresa" => "corporate-events",
                  "Showroom" => "showroom",
                  "Despacho" => "office",
                  "Sala multiusos" => "sala-multiusos",
                  "Puesto de Coworking" => "puesto-de-trabajo",
                  "Sala para conferencias" => "sala-para-conferencias",
                  "Sala de terapias" =>"sala-de-terapias",
                  "Otras salas" => "otras-salas",
                  "Espacio para rodaje" => "espacio-para-rodaje",
                  "Multiespacio" => "multiespacio",
                  "Fiesta de Navidad" => "christmas-events",
                  "Presentación de producto" => "product-presentation",
                  "Pop-up Stores" => "pop-up-stores",
                  "Show cooking" => "kitchen-studio",
                  "Shooting" => "shooting",
                  "Teatro" => "theater",
                  "Baile" => "dance-practice",
                  "Yoga" => "yoga",
                  "Performance" => "performance",
                  "Sala para fiestas particulares" => "sala-para-eventos"
```

As you can see, I have put the internationalization in the model, but when I want a dropdown with this, no internationalization.

Helper:

```
def categories
  @categories = Room::CATEGORY_COLLECTION
  @category_selected = Room::FILTER_CATEGORY_COLLECTION
end
```

Dropdown:

```
<%= f.select :categories_name_in, options_for_select(@categories, @category_selected), { include_blank: t('all_categories') }, { class: 'selectbox' } %>
```

The dropdown always appears in Spanish...

### Thanks!

EDIT:
I have tried with more categories with no translation and it seems that the dropdown puts spanish as default language (screenshot from english locale website):
[image]

Any clue?

Comment: You should check the value of `@categories` .

Comment: Many thanks for your quick answer. @categories is defined by category collection. I have tried I18n.t(:meeting_rooms) but doesn't work :(

Comment: Production website: www.spaces-on.com What is really strange is that it doesn't give an error, it takes the word in Spanish...

Comment: Did you set the correct locale? Try to pass the locale params: for example: `I18n.t('meeting_rooms', locale: 'en')`

Comment: If I do this, it works indeed but when I set the language to other, it stays with the locale

Comment: Your dropdown getting values from `CATEGORY_COLLECTION` hash. when you use @categories.key ,this get all the keys i.e.( Aula de formación,Sala para entrevistas) and when you use @categories.values, this get all the values i.e. (aula-de-formacion,sala-para-entrevistas) . Try this and reply to me.

Comment: Hi Pardeep, if use categories.key, it gives me error. If I use categories.keys, it happens the same as before (all in Spanish). I am sure if it was what you meant? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.select :categories_name_in, options_for_select(@categories.values, @category_selected), { include_blank: t('all_categories') }, { class: 'selectbox' } %>
```

You need to use **@categories.values** insteadof **@categoties**

Comment: Many thanks for your answer!! If I put category.values, I have the value of the category (ie sala-de-reuniones, event-space...) not the user-friendly category name...